# CakePHP DebugKit loaded but not showing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-debug-kit

I created a fresh isntallation of CakePHP 4 with composer.
I am using wamp on localhost. After DB config, everything works fine on the default homepage, including the debugkit icon on the bottom right.

**However, uploading the same project to my online server, debugkit icon does not show up.**

No error message, no JS errors in the console.

Here is the [phpinfo](http://cell-dent.hu/phpinfo.php) of my server.

How to troubleshoot this?

[image: DebugKit showing on localhost]

[image: DebugKit not showing on online server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.

It is intended that DebugKit does not show up on live servers.
If you still want to use it on your live server, here is how to do it:

Add this line to the end of bootstrap.php:

```
Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but here is my answer: I found this post with the same curiosity, in my case I am not using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html), I am using [LARAGON](https://laragon.org/) , it is similar to XAMPP but it is more configurable and it gives me the possibility to directly configure SSL in each installation for local development, test the development in a more real way and put it into production without many operational differences.

In the case that you are using [LARAGON](https://laragon.org/) and CAKEPHP 4 for example it is normal that we get the legend "[DebugKit is loaded](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html)" [(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbTlH.jpg) but we are not displaying the cake logo in the lower right margin; in my case the only thing I had to do is find the **config \ bootstrap.php** [(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0825.jpg) and at the end of that file put what it says << rhinoeli >> and it works accordingly.

```
Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', true);
```

Don't forget to delete the code block you put in when it's time to go to production.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

where composer.json file is located  run

```
php composer.phar require --dev cakephp/debug_kit "~4.0"
```

and run

```
    bin/cake plugin load DebugKit

    bin/cake plugin assets symlink
```